# How to integrate Linphone into an existing project (SIP in IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, linphone

**I am looking for integrate Linphone library in my ios project. And I dont find tutorial to help me. This project offers very little documentation, but seems to work well.**

- For information, here is the project page which provides its open source code :

  [Linphone open source code](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html)
- I already compiled sources by following all steps and this work very well, But the next step is to integrate a part of code in my personal iPhone project for use SIP layer, with the management of audio and video.

In the case of my use, it will not be the user but the application that will automatically call if needed (my project is for home automation system).

The Linphone application seems very complex to integrate into other projets, because there is a lot of library to include and lot of configurations ...

I have not found any examples on the internet and I confess I do not know where to start without help, without a way to do the integration.

***So if you have any source (tutorial) that can help me or if you have ever experienced to integrate this library, this held me a very great help.***

Comment: have you integrated succesfully?please provide some data if so

Comment: @Chigurh My goal is communications between a phone and a machine to machine module. But linphone is really complicated to integrate into an existing project. So I decided to integrate my application in linphone ios existing project. This requires studying the ios linphone code and see a bit about how it uses the linphone library. That was easy for me because the bulk of the application project revolves around linphone. I moved parts modified visual, off unused portions, add my parts. I had to do this for reasons of time too. From scratch with only the library that proved too complicated for me

Comment: Hi, i am getting ortp/ortp.h not found error. Can you please tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: @Beber facing same issue how to solved  this issue ?

Answer (score 10):

When you build linphone you already have a Xcode project that integrates those libraries. You can start inspecting this.
As you will notice there is a class called LinphoneManager that manages the way the application uses linphone libraries (you can see it as a façade).
So if you want to integrate linphone in your own project you will have to include **linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include** and **linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib**.
Good luck.

Source link
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0DwszanZcPhV0doNm5rMHdWa28&export=download

Comment: Hi.. I am getting `ortp/ortp.h` not found. error.. how to resolve it ?

Comment: Hi, you have to add on your Xcode project -> Build Settings -> Search Path / Header Search Path, the following lines:  submodules/linphone/coreapi submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/include submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/include submodules/linphone/oRTP/include submodules/externals/gsm/ submodules/externals/osip/include submodules/externals/exosip/include submodules/externals/speex/include Classes/Utils/NinePatch/ Classes/Utils/XMLRPC/ include

Comment: yes I did...Also tried to put those all files to that path of my project but could not run project...

Comment: @Maulik what's the exact error? Did you copy all the content of liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include and liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib to your Xcode project? Another hint I could think of is marking all .a with target membership to your current target.

Comment: yes all the files. I getting ortp/ortp.h not found. How to make all .a with target ?

Comment: @Maulik In Xcode you must go to file inspector, then check target membership on your target. You must do it for all files .a in lib. (libort.a, libavutil.a, ...)

Comment: Hi can you please help me on this http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-users/2011-11/msg00014.html I am getting this error while compiling....

Comment: Hi..can you tell me how to add friends with `linphone_core_add_friend` in linphone ? I wanted to know best practice to add friends from address book

Comment: The  2 (folders  linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include and linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib) are of size 130 mb.How to reduce the size of the project.Linphone soft phone(the one in the App Store )is only 10 mb.what all files should i delete to reduce the size?

Comment: Hai i am facing the same problem...ortp/ortp.h not found. how could you solve?.. i am just trying to compile the linphone.xcodeProj from Github..

Comment: Hello Guys, Can anyone please let me know how you resolved error of ortp/ortp.h not found.. i have downloaded github project and building it.. Thank you

Comment: Hello, can any one give the link which steps need to follow after cloning the code from "git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-iphone.git --recursive"?? 
Right now I have clone the code and download the "linphone-sdk" from above doc link. And now am facing error "linphone/linphone_tunnel.h" file is missing. Can anybody has suggestion??

Comment: Hello There, compiling the code can be done by following this link: http://blog.codylab.com/ios-build-linphone-iphone-sdk/