# Integrate Linphone in own iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, sip, linphone

I am creating a voip call based project with Linphone and I have also successfully build and run the Linphone project and successfully run audio and video call. Now I am integrating Linphone in my own project and I am facing many problems and issues with this. I have used some following links for help but nowhere are complete instructions. Can anyone provide me the complete running steps for this-

http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/

[Integrate Linphone app to my iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081140/integrate-linphone-app-to-my-ios-app)

[How to integrate Linphone into an existing project (SIP in IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609763/how-to-integrate-linphone-into-an-existing-project-sip-in-ios)

http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/overview

[How to integrate Linphone into an existing project (SIP in IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609763/how-to-integrate-linphone-into-an-existing-project-sip-in-ios?lq=1)

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2014-09/msg00109.html

http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Download Liblinphone iPhone SDK from the link:  http://www.linphone.org/releases/ios choose latest one.
- Move two folders (**include** and **lib**) to your project folder
- Add paths to these folders in your project **Build settings** - INCLUDE folder goes to **headers** and LIB folder goes to **libraries**.
- In **General** tab in **Linked frameworks** add all files from **LIB** folder
- Download/clone the repo https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone
- Find 4 files: **LinphoneManager.h/.m** and **Utils.h/.m** , include them in your project folder and add them to the left pane to other class files also
- Try to compile your project - xCode will spam you with errors - this is ok.
- You need to inspect errors and just delete all file imports causing errors (Some Linphone Address book files/ some config store files and some helpers classes that you *do not need for basic use* in your project (because most likely you already implemented this features in your existing project))
- Then compile again and inspect all errors in methods. Comment delete any problematic chunks of code (there will be about 10-15 of them).

LinphoneManager class already include many useful features - like good watch and use of linphone core with good logging and etc and etc, but not all of them (unfortunately).

Comment: Download Liblinphone iPhone SDK from the link: http://www.linphone.org/releases/ios/ and choose latest one.

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinov -  I have clone the repo, In Linphone app, liblinphone sdk was missing then i have downloaded Liblinphone sdk as mentioned you above and run then libbelcard.a,libbelr.a library showing missing(in redcolor), I have deleted that library and run it. It is finally run on simulator 6 and 6+, But when i run on device it is running successfully but during login it is crashing on device but not on simulator, Please Advice, Thanks,
Crashing log: [_NSInlineData bytes]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: @DharmendraKumarRajan Looks like some object being deallocated while you still need it. Looks like you've created variable inside some method and it have been deallocated after method has finished its tasks. Try to make instance variables. It's really hard to point in the right direction here.

Comment: @NikolaLukic it's not folder - it's inside of one of the project Tabs in XCode. Go to project (top blue icon among projects file - then choose General tab then scroll down to Frameworks section).

Comment: I am not able to find these two folders (include and lib). and also this link is not working. 
http://www.linphone.org/releases/ios/liblinphone-iphone-sdk-latest.zip

Comment: Hi @AndreiKonstantinov, Please let me know where we can get the linphone session.

Answer (score 5):

With Xcode 11 using macos 10.15.6 Catalina

## Linphone SDK 4.4.0 Using Cocoapod

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-sdk/blob/master/README.md

Using a local linphone SDK
Clone the linphone-sdk repository from out gitlab:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git --recursive 
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Or

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git
```

Rebuild the project:

PODFILE_PATH= pod install
where is your build directory of the linphone-sdk project, containing the linphone-sdk.podspec file and a linphone-sdk ouptut directory comprising built frameworks and resources.

Pod file looks like

---

```
source "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git"
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"

def common_pods
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'linphone-sdk', '4.4.0'
end
```

Then open linphone.xcworkspace with Xcode to build and run the app.

## Linphone SDK 4.4.0 Using Compile

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git -- recursive
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Or

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git
```

Goto the build directory

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
```

———————————

https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-cmake-builder/blob/ios-3.13.19/README.python.md

first, install brew

```
$ brew install cmake
$ brew install yasm
$ brew install pkg-config
```

Install pip ->

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py

$ python -m pip install pystache //Check by $ python -m pip list

$ brew install doxygen
```

———————————

```
$ cmake .. -G Xcode -DLINPHONESDK_PLATFORM=IOS -DENABLE_G729=YES -DENABLE_G729B_CNG=YES -DENABLE_VCARD=OFF -DENABLE_ILBC=OFF -DENABLE_SILK=OFF -DENABLE_ISAC=OFF -DENABLE_MKV=OFF -DENABLE_GSM=OFF -DENABLE_DOC=OFF -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_LIME=OFF -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=OFF -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=OFF
```

Note - in this step we will also enable G729 dedec support in our linphone sdk.

```
$ cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
```

The compilation process is done now need to integrate with Xcode

## Compiled Linphone SDK integrates into Xcode.

Find compiled sdk in below directory
linphone-sdk -> build -> linphone-sdk -> apple-darwin

1. Frameworks and share folder add into xcode project, Frameworks have multiple universal architectures.
2. Frameworks path add into framework search in build settings
3. Every framework of Frameworks folder, should be type "embed and sign" (means embed framework.) instead of "do not embed" as default while adding into Xcode Framework setting. it's the most very important part.
4. apple-darwin -> Tools folder have deply.sh script, copy its contents and create a new run script in "build settings" and paste in it"
5. the tricky part is where to place the 4th point's script for upload app using archive with strip and slice. Edit Scheme -> Archive -> open dropdown -> post actions -> + to add new script -> copy and paste.

6 (Optional). If experience script causes application crash due to fat library used our project, There is a minor change in the script, I found a solution from this URL - [Errors building Xcode Project after adding in Run Script fatal error: lipo: input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240330/errors-building-xcode-project-after-adding-in-run-script-fatal-error-lipo-inpu)

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
    echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

# Start of Script modify - identify if the framework is FAT. If it is, then it skips it.
    if [ ! -f "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    if xcrun lipo -info "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" | grep --silent "Non-fat"; then
        echo "Framework non-fat, skipping: $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        continue
    fi

    echo "Thinning framework $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
# end of Script modify

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

7. If you are using pod then de integrate pod using terminal command "pod deintegrate" on your pod directory. also delete .xcworkspace file from the project.
8. Now install pod using terminal command "pod install"

Note: If your case was Adding script causes app crash as I mentioned in 6th point but every time adding the script, have to pod de integrate help me avoid it.

:) Now enjoy using linphone sdk in your project.

## end of linphone sdk

## Linphone SDK Configuration in our projects.

1. Enable Codec - To enable audio codec first enable defaultValue of g729_preference in the Audio.plist file and last step In Project -> Target -> Build Settings find "Preprocessor macros" and include HAVE_G729, it prints in sip log like Adding G729/8000 for compatibility, just in case.

#Update - add 5th point fo compile for upload the app to the app store and G729 codec configuration.

Comment: i tried to compile using above steps but getting below error 
"The following build commands failed:
 PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ Rules build/linphone-sdk.build/Debug/ios-armv7.build/Script-8B6947E693B44EA0845EC051.sh"
So can you help me to resolve this error?

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani two probability can be submodule not get fetch in a git repo or not install CMake please check dependency in https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-sdk/blob/master/README.md.   can you tell in which step of compilation you got stuck?

Comment: i am stuck using below command
$ cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo

Comment: @RaviKumar Can you tell how can I use linphone sdk to call to a phone number? What configuration may be needed? We already have PBX server ready.

Comment: @MasterAgentX as per my understanding, call to mobile number instead of sip user, is server side configuration, we just have to call using mobile number instead of sip user id (as per linphone code). the server should understand "mobile number" is not sip user id so they make it an outbound call to carrier mobile number. other than I don't have idea. if you find it, please share with us, we will appreciate.

Comment: @RaviKumar have you got any solution?

Comment: @RaviKumar 
(1 failure)
make: *** [/Users/mac/Documents/shraddha_linphoone/linphone-sdk/build/ios-armv7-prefix/src/ios-armv7-stamp/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios-armv7-build] Error 65
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
Facing this error at the time of build.So can you please hemp me?

Comment: @RaviKumar complied linphone successfully but which place set PODFILE_PATH?
can you please help me?

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani we complied because few features did not have in linphone sdk using cocoa pod. so after you did compile you don't need to use pod items for linphone sdk. if you are troubling cocoa pod related issue in that case this question is not appropriate.

Comment: @RaviKumar 
linephone sdk compiled added in code but in audio codec list not display G729 codec but  in linphone sdk build folder checked g729 codec .a file genrated.
so can you please help me for how to  display the G729 codec in codec list and used for call?

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani I update the answer with the configuration of enabling codec. hope it helps you.

Comment: @RaviKumar
Thank you for update answer but still not display g729 in codec list.In log we are getting below
linphone[9168:172722] [Message] Codec G729/8000 fmtp=[annexb=yes] number=18, default enablement: 16) added to the list of possible codecs.

Could not find encoder for G729

so can you please help me.

Comment: @RaviKumar
i want used only compile sdk not used pod of linphone so can you please suggest me how to used linphone sdk only?

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani please understand the above-mentioned step is only for compiled sdk, not for cocoapod. I mentioned the 7th and 8th steps make you confused, i will remove it. your g729 is not enabled just because of linphone using pod.

Comment: @RaviKumarremoved pod and now only used compiled sdk but getting error like. "No such module 'linphonesw'".
linphonesw folder create in apple-darwinare---->share-->linphonesw.So how to add in project?

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani please remove import linphonesw because you are not using pod's import and linphonesw.swift class into your project as you can find in complied sdk folders. you will also got error in override mathod so you need to use as per used in its base classes.

Comment: @RaviKumar I'm using linphone-sdk pod in my project. In Finder, the pod's size is approx 305 MB only. Can we use this to get a compiled version? I want to reduce my app size.

Comment: On this Step "cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo", i am getting this error, 



The following build commands failed:
 PhaseScriptExecution Generate\ ios-armv7-prefix/src/ios-armv7-stamp/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/ios-armv7-build /Users/haseebjaved/Desktop/recursive/build/linphone-sdk.build/RelWithDebInfo-iphonesimulator/ios-armv7.build/Script-9303CE8FA6A148D2AA771A8E.sh