# Errors building Xcode Project after adding in Run Script fatal error: lipo: input file

Tags: ios, xcode, run-script

I had the following errors when attempting to upload my app to the App Store ERROR ITMS-90087, ERROR ITMS-90209, & ERROR ITMS-90125 as outlined in this Question [Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues/30866648#comment58171799_30866648) and used the script shown below to try and fix the problem:

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

Now I'm getting a lot of errors trying to compile my code in Xcode.

```
Executable is /Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-egnqksafjoylrcaxerbjrknmxdgl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[AppName].app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts
Extracting arm64 from Bolts

fatal error: lipo: input file (/Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-egnqksafjoylrcaxerbjrknmxdgl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[AppName].app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified

Merging extracted architectures: arm64
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-egnqksafjoylrcaxerbjrknmxdgl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[AppName].app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts-arm64 (No such file or directory)

rm: /Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-egnqksafjoylrcaxerbjrknmxdgl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[AppName].app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts-arm64: No such file or directory

Replacing original executable with thinned version
mv: rename /Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-egnqksafjoylrcaxerbjrknmxdgl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[AppName].app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts-merged to /Users/[Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-egnqksafjoylrcaxerbjrknmxdgl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[AppName].app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well it seems that Bolts framework is not a fat binary (i.e. Does not contain multiple architectures binaries) hence the extraction and merging fails. I guess the simplest solution will be to run the script only for specific frameworks that comes with a binary for x86_64 arch. You can identify fat binaries using the 'file' command.

Comment: After reading this, I realised since only one framework was causing the upload problem to the App Store, then that should only be the framework that I need to run the script to. So I changed the line in the script find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK to only reference the one framework causing the error i.e. find "$APP_PATH" -name '[frameworkname].framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK

Comment: Fixed my issue too with running the script only for specific framework for which you get x86_64 error.

Comment: For me, that script above will work on the first try. Afterwards, I get errors stating it's trying to remove slices for architectures that aren't there. I can get it work again if and only if I use the Clean command in Xcode (Shift + Command + K). When I click Build or Run, it works again. Any idea how to go around this issue?

Comment: SamoanProgrammer comment is the solution. Mario I also had to clean and build.

Comment: Any idea how to modify this if you have two frameworks causing problems?

Comment: @JakeT. see the answer that I added to the main thread.  I've added some additional checking to work around the multiple framework issue.

Answer (score 19):

I've edited the script to try and identify if the framework is FAT.  If it is, then it skips it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"

    if [ ! -f "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    if xcrun lipo -info "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" | grep --silent "Non-fat"; then
        echo "Framework non-fat, skipping: $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        continue
    fi

    echo "Thinning framework $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        xcrun lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    xcrun lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just checking the "Run script only when installing" option?

Comment: It worked for me, but I am afraid for any issue while deploying app to App store.