# SKMaps(Skobbler maps) Integrated Application uploading error

Tags: app-store-connect, ios10, xcode8, skmaps

I have integrated SKMaps without pods in my app. When i were uploading it to App Store, it started throwing me error like this

[image]

Does anyone have any solution?

**UPDATE**

I have added the script as provided here in this link:http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

But after adding script, app started giving too many errors for other frameworks.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have checked this answer: [Errors building Xcode Project after adding in Run Script fatal error: lipo: input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240330/errors-building-xcode-project-after-adding-in-run-script-fatal-error-lipo-inpu)

Then, i tried to run that script only for SKMaps framework, then uploading the app again is giving same error again.

Answer (score 2):

What version of the SDK are you using? 
Is it the static library or module? 
The issue could be caused by using the module target which contains all architectures (including simulator one, which could be considered invalid by Apple when submitting the app). 
However, other clients have successfully submitted the app recently and had no reported issues.

Comment: Hello @adrian-b, I am also getting the same issue while trying to publish the app. How can we remove the simulator architectures from the build ?