# Alamofire Fat binary issue with Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode10.1

I am updating Alamofire frameworks for support of Swift 4.2 in my project which earlier supported only Swift3. I am using Xcode 10.1. When I updated Alamofire, then I am getting **fatal error :**

> "Lipo: input file (Path) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified"

Although I am able to build and run, but it's showing above error, So I am worried why it's happening I have no idea whether it's because of Xcode 10 or something else. I tried everywhere but no luck. Please help me to understand below points:

1. Before updating Alamofire to Xcode 10 it creates FAT binary for Alamofire.
2. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240330/errors-building-xcode-project-after-adding-in-run-script-fatal-error-lipo-inpu), have applied suggested script to ignore if framework is not FAT binary and all errors gone. So can I consider that updated Alamofire framework is not FAT binary or Can I say it's universal framework for which it will work for every architecture?

Comment: "I am using XCode4.1"... 4.1??

Comment: Sorry, thanks :) updated question