# linphone integration with iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, linphone-sdk

I am trying to integrate my app with linphone SDK, But i get the following error:

ld: '/VOIPApp/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/libopus.a(celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When i disable the BITCODE i get huge of errors

Comment: what errors you are getting after changing Bitecode.

Comment: Showing Recent Messages
  "_res_9_ninit", referenced from:


      _dns_resconf_loadfromresolv in libbellesip.a(dns.c.o)

Comment: about 198 errors

Comment: ok.. have you set link under 'OtherLinker flags' in app settings?

Comment: i set it with -ObjC

Comment: Look at this link for integration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361502/integrate-linphone-in-own-ios-project

Comment: Thanks @Gagan_iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled the bitcode although it was enabled in the linphone sample and added the following libs:

```
libz.dylib
libiconv.dylib
libxml2.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
libc++.dylib
libstdc++.6.dylib
libresolv.dylib
```

and it works :)

Comment: Working fine at my end